# How can I export civicrm contribution along with its price set fields?

Tags: civireport

I want to export the civicrm contributions. I want the priceset fields to be included in the report. I am trying to export them in Contributions->Find Contributions->Export Contributions 
While selecting the fields I want all the priceset fields in the option. How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at eileen's [Extended Report Extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport) which includes

- Extended Report - Contributions with Price Set data
- Extended Report - Price Set Line Items

Answer (score 0):

Currently, contribution level searches and reports will only show you the contribution level information, not the line item detail (a.k.a. the price field options selected on the contribution). Take a look at Reports > Contribution Reports > Bookkeeping Transaction report - this report will show you the financial type of each price field option selected.

Hope this helps,
Tamar